# Showing multiple lines on Acumatica charts

Tags: acumatica

I am trying to build a chart comparing Actual and Budgeted expenses per Department. I created GI that has columns Department, Budget Amount and Actual Amount.

Any chart type can show either of these amounts.

Is there a way to show both amounts per Department on the same chart?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did not find a way to add a second independent value because there is only a single value field in chart configuration.

It is however possible to have a breakdown of the value. In chart design mode, edit the chart and try the `Series Legend` field.

[image]

For example, I started with this chart that shows `Activity Count` per Sales Person:
[image]

And I added a breakdown per activity `Status` in the `Legend` field:
[image]

This fulfills the requirement to have multiple lines in the chart but each line is still showing an aggregate value on the same `Activity Count All` field.

Comment: Thank you Hugues. This is an original logic!

Comment: You can investigate configuration through Power BI as an alternative: https://www.augforums.com/power-bi-tile-dashboard-widget-in-acumatica-6/

Comment: Hi Hugues, thank you for the link. It shows how to show Power BI tile on the dashboard. My understanding is that the data it shows come from Power BI, not from GI which is the case here.                                                                               Still, the link is helpful - I was planning to link Acumatica to Power BI. Your help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Correct, this is not an Acumatica chart.

Comment: BI Chart is not a problem. The problem is that this chart does not show Acumatica data from GI.

Comment: Power BI and chart widget is heavy on configuration. I believe you would have to configure Power BI connector in Acumatica External Applications page first.

Comment: Thank you Hugues. if I configure Power BI connector, would I be able to show GI results using Power BI widgets?

Comment: I believe the answer is yes but I haven't investigated.  AUG forum is currently the best resource about Acumatica/PowerBI integration: https://www.augforums.com/forums/acumatica-odata-with-microsoft-excel-and-power-bi/

Comment: Acumatica had a webinar on General Business Edition 2021 today, and the Product Manager said that passing GI data to PowerBI is indeed doable. I guess, this is the only way to do proper charts. Thank you so much for all your help! Best regards.